# Deetctar tecla apretada con javascript de un include php

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, modal

Tengo una pagina `.php (un formulario)`
que en cierto lugar del código hago un `include php` que es un modal con otro formulario:

```
 include("modal/ticket_pago.php");
```

Y luego bien abajo del `php` ejecuto:

```
     $( document ).ready(function() {

     $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        // alert(e.which);
        switch (e.which) {

                  case 113://f2
                    enviarTicket();
                    break;
                  case 114://f4
                    guardarTicket();
                    break;
                }                                        
                });                
});
```

Si no abro el modal y oprimo `f2`, la función `enviarTicket()` se ejecuta bien,
pero si abro el modal y oprimo `f4`, no se ejecuta `guardarTicket()`.
Es algo de que al html del modal no le registra el evento `keydown`, supongo que es porque este es un ¿`include php`?. ¿Cómo se puede solucionar esto?. 
Gracias.

Resumido el include ticket_pago.php es el siguiente,es un modal bootstrap, si apreto cualquier tecla sin el modal abierto funciona bien, toma los eventos del teclado, pero si abro el modal con modalTicketEFCO.modal("show") , y apreto cualquier tecla no toma los eventos del teclado:

```html
<?php $valor=$_GET["monto"];?>
<div class="modal fade "  id="modalTiketEFCO" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" data-backdrop="false">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="border-style: solid;  border-width: 2px;" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px">
    <div class="modal-header" style="padding: 2px; margin: 2px">
       <h5 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
        Cobrar
       </h5> 
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
       </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <form>
       <input type="text" id="monto" name="monto"  value="<?php echo $valor;?>"  >
       </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
        Cobrar
       </button> 
       
      </div>
     </div>
     
    </div>
    
   </div>
   
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que el modal es un include? Javascript se ejecuta en el cliente y no puede comunicarse con PHP, que se ejecuta en el servidor, a menos que haya una llamada AJAX de por medio.

Comment: Seria recomendable que pusieras el código HTML y el javascript

Comment: El código para la tecla f4 es 115 no 114

Comment: Por favor incluye también el HTML que te genera tu include para ayudarte